# How to load a 3x3 matrix correctly from data file?

Tags: java, matrix, loading

I'm working on a Tic-Tac-Toe project, in which I import the 9 character string of X's and O's:

```
XOOXXOOXX
```

I then have to split it apart, load it into a 3x3 matrix, then test and see who won the game. I have written the code to load the file and run the game like so:

```
public static void main( String args[] ) throws IOException
{
    Scanner importer = new Scanner(new File("testdata.dat"));

    int count = importer.nextInt();
    System.out.println(count + " games to test.");


    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        String game = importer.next();

        TicTacToe gamecalc = new TicTacToe();

        System.out.println(gamecalc.getWinner(game));
    }
}
```

However, when I try to load the 3x3 matrix already established like this:

```
String gamedata = game; //gamedata is passed in, reassigned to game

for(int line = 0; line < 2; line++) {
        for(int column = 0; column < 2; column++) {

        gamemat[line][column] = game.charAt(line * column);

        }
    }
```

and the data set being:

```
abcdefghi
jklmnopqr
stuvwxyz1
234567890
ABCDEFGHI
```

The result ends up being, when printing with Arrays.toString:

```
[a, a,  ][a, b,  ][ ,  ,  ] //each line is one 3x3 matrix
[j, j,  ][j, k,  ][ ,  ,  ]
[s, s,  ][s, t,  ][ ,  ,  ]
[2, 2,  ][2, 3,  ][ ,  ,  ]
[A, A,  ][A, B,  ][ ,  ,  ]
```

How can I rework my algorithm to get the matrix to load correctly? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this line is wrong...

```
gamemat[line][column] = game.charAt(line * column);
```

Should probably be...

```
gamemat[line][column] = game.charAt(line * 3 + column);
```

Also, you probably want the loops to count up to 3...

```
for(line = 0; line < 3; line++)...
```